# Why this time is not parsed?

Tags: .net, datetime, time

**Why** does this time is not parsed ? (CurrentCulture = "en-US", LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss", TimeSeparator = ":")

```
  Dim test As TimeSpan
  Dim result As Boolean = TimeSpan.TryParseExact("15:16:42", "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, test)
```

**result** variable is False ...

Comment: `TimeSpan` is more finicky than `DateTime` when it comes to format strings - use `"HH\\:mm\\:ss"` instead,

Comment: @DStanley Result is the same ...

Comment: I just realized you're using VB.  In that case it should be `"hh\:mm\:ss"`  Note that `HH` is not a valid format since `TimeSpan` is a _duration_ and does not have AM/PM distinction.  If you want to represent a _time of day_ then use `DateTime` and format appropriately.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks a lot !